# How to keep data safe with azure mobile services and ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, azure-mobile-services

I am connecting to my Azure mobile services server through my javascript files. Meaning i create the client in the controllers page and sort/update/delete data there. Is this a safe way to access my database? Do I have to use another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can control access to the table as a whole with the access
>   property:
>
> - `authenticated` means you must be logged in to access the endpoint. If you are not authenticated, a 401 Unauthorized response will be
>     returned.
> - `anonymous` means anyone can access the endpoint.
> - `disabled` means the table is invisible. The server will return a 405 Method Not Allowed response.
>
> Normally, you would only use authenticated as an access value at the
>   table level. You can also set access at the operation level, and that is
>   why this option exists. Anonymous access is the default.

From https://shellmonger.com/2016/04/15/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-8-table-controller-basics/

You can do this from Easy tables settings in the [Azure portal](http://portal.azure.com).

[image]

Before you change the table permission to `authenticated`, you'll need to add authentication to your mobile app first. For more information, please refer to [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-cordova-get-started-users).

Answer (score 0):

Controlling access to your database via a REST API where you can do authentication and authorization checks plus data validation is absolutely the right way to go.  Azure Mobile Apps is just one way to get there (in my, potentially biased, opinion, it's one of the better ways).  However, it isn't the only way.  You should certainly consider your requirements when making such a decision.